# Why is an empty string '' encoded into 2 bytes in utf-16 but 0 bytes in utf-8 or ascii?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, utf-16, utf

I was just learning about encoding strings in python and after fidgeting with it a little, I got confused by the fact that the size of an empty string ('') is 0 in utf 8 and ascii but somehow 2 in utf 16? how come?

```
print(len(''.encode('utf16'))) # is 2
print(len(''.encode('utf8'))) # is 0
```

I guess a big part of the problem is that I don't understand how utf 16 works. I don't understand why encoding 'spam' in utf 16 would be 10 bytes long instead of just 8 bytes (2 bytes (16 bits) for each character). I'm assuming that the 2 bytes are needed in utf 16 as default for any string for padding or something?

*edit

I am NOT confused about the basics of how UTF 8 or UTF 16 work and differ in storing each individual characters. I am confused about how the absence of any characters (an empty string) would be stored in 2 bytes in UTF 16 but have 0 bytes in UTF 8. (as opposed to 1 byte or 0 for both)

The link does not provide answer to my question.

Comment: "Duplicate" link is wrong: The difference here is the BOM, not the encoding per se.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Python includes a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) when encoding to UTF-16, but not when encoding to UTF-8.

```
>>> ''.encode('utf16')
b'\xff\xfe'
>>> ''.encode('utf8')
b''
```

You can suppress the BOM by explicitly specifying the byte order with a `BE` (Big-Endian) or `LE` (Little-Endian) suffix.

```
>>> ''.encode('utf-16-le')
b''
```